# Convert VARCHAR to DATE in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I have VARCHAR column (MyValue) in my table. It has date value in two different format.

```
MyValue
----------
25-10-2016
2016-10-13
```

I would like to show them in DATE format.

I wrote query like below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, MyValue, 105) FROM MyTable
SELECT CAST(MyValue as date) FROM MyTable
```

Both are giving me this error. `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Is there anyway convert to DATE datatype format even the value stored in different formats like above?

Expecting your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `case`  expression to do the appropriate cast/convert depending on date format.

Comment: These two formats are just examples. It may be stored in any other formats as well.

Comment: dont store dates as varchar  because that is a bad idea. Why is this a bad idea ? Well just look at the troubles you are in now because of it

Comment: @good-to-know, still a case expression is the way to go.

Comment: @GuidoG, I assume OP has already learned the lesson now, trying to clean up the mixed dates now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
declare @varchardates table
(
vcdate varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @varchardates VALUES
('25-10-2016'),
('2016-10-13')

SELECT CONVERT(date,vcdate, case when SUBSTRING(vcdate, 3, 1) = '-' 
THEN 105 ELSE 126 END) as mydate 
FROM @varchardates
```

Depending on how many different formats you have in your data, you may need to extend the case statement!

See [here](http://sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx) for list of the different format numbers

Comment: @good-to-know Check the page that I linked.  This shows all the common format numbers.  Basically you just need to ensure that the case statement picks up all the formats you use.  If you allow lots of formats, it could get messy!

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has the TRY_CONVERT, TRY_PARSE methods that make it a lot easier to try multiple formats

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT` and `COALESCE`. [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) returns NULL if the conversion fails, [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) returns the first NOT NULL value:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, x, 105), TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, x, 120))
FROM    (VALUES('25-10-2016'), ('2016-10-13')) a(x)
```

I assumed the value `2016-10-13` is in format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

You mention in a comment you may have other formats as well. In that case it gets very tricky. If you get a value `01-12-2017` and you have no idea about the format, there is **no way** to tell whether this is a date in januari or in december.

Comment: TRY_CONVERT was introduced in 2012 version, COALESCE in 2008 version; so yes, it should work.

Comment: because it is showing  function error Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I don't have 2012 installation to test at the moment. If I set my compatibility level to 110 it still works. If I set it to 100 (2008 R2) it fails with the error you mention. So it should work...

Comment: Not compatible with SQL Server 2012! :-(

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you (perhaps compatability level issue), but it definitely should [work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLktsW5qBjE&t=1m33s).